# How to declare appropriate size for the buffer

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, memory-management, buffer-overflow

I'm using `TCHAR` in the Visual C++ poject I'm working on, which definition is shown below:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
#else
    typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

I need to put some data into buffer `buff`:

```
char buff[size] = {0};  // how to declare the buffer size - what should be its value ?
sprintf(buff, "%s (ID: %i)", res->name(), res->id());
```

where:

`name()` returns `TCHAR*`

`id()` returns `int`

How to calculate the value of `size` - exact buffer capacity for actual needs (smaller if no unicode is defined, bigger if unicode is defined) ? In addition I'd like to protect myself from buffer overflow possibility, what kind of protection should I use ?

What's more, I've declared here the buffer as `char`. If I declare the buffer as `int`, would it be any difference for the size value (i.e 4 times smaller if compared to declared as char) ?

**UPDATE**

What I come up with partially based on Mats Petersson answer is:

```
    size_t len;
    const char *FORMAT;
#ifndef _UNICODE
    len = strlen((char*)res->name()); 
    FORMAT = "%s (ID: %i)";
#else
    len = wcslen(res->name());
    FORMAT = "%S (ID: %i)";
#endif    

    int size = 7 * sizeof(TCHAR) +                             /* place for characters inside format string */
               len * sizeof(TCHAR) +                           /* place for "name" characters */
               strlen(_itoa(id, ioatmp, 10)) * sizeof(TCHAR) + /* place for "id" digits */
               1 * sizeof(TCHAR);                              /* zero byte(s) string terminator */

    char *buff = new char[size];  /* buffer has to be declared dynamically on the heap,
                                   * because its exact size is not known at compilation time */
    sprintf(buff, FORMAT, name, id);
    delete[] buff;
```

Is it correct thinking or did I miss something ?

Comment: `buff[size * sizeof(TCHAR) / sizeof(char)]`?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: No, the size is what I'm actually asking about - I want to learn how the value of size should be calculated, based on the fact I know what data will be passed into it (the data: `"%s (ID: %i)", res->name(), res->id()`).

Answer (score 1):

To begin from the back, `buff` should always be `char`, because that's what is being stored by `sprintf`.

Second, if your `res->name()` is returning a wide-char (unicode) string, your format string should use `"%S"`, for regular ASCII you should use `"%s"`.

Now, to calculate the length required for the buffer, and avoid overflows. It's not that hard to do something like

```
      const TCHAR *nm = res->name();
      size_t len; 
#ifndef UNICODE
      len = strlen(nm); 
#else
      ... see below. 
#endif
```

and then guesstimate the length of the number (an integer can't take more than 12 places), along with the exact number of characters produced as constants in the format string.

This works fine for the standard ASCII variant.

However, it gets more fun with the wide char variant, as that can take up multiple bytes in the output string (e.g. writing Chinese characters that always require multibyte encoding). One solution is:

```
 len = snprintf(0, NULL, "%S", nm);
```

which should give you the correct number [I think]. It's a pretty cumbersome method, but it will work. I'm not sure there is an easy way to convert a wide-string to "number of bytes needed to store this string" in another way.

Edit: I would seriously consider if it's much point in supporting non-UNICOD veariant, and then just convert the whole thing to using `swprintf(...)` instead. You still need the length, but it should just be the result of of `wcslen(res->name())`, rather than requiring some complex conversion calculation.

Comment: Along with my edit at the bottom, I have attempted to clarify the `%S` vs. `%s` situation.

Comment: Note that that use of sprintf is non-portable (but then, neither are TCHARs, heh).

Also you should use _tcsclen(...) to correctly get the length of a TCHAR in units of the type,
`size_t byteLen = _tcsclen(res->name()) * sizeof(TCHAR);`

Comment: @Mats Petersson: +1 Thanks for your time. Can you check the update to my question where I did the calculation ? Does it look right ? What with the place for characters inside format string, should I calculate it as `7 * sizeof(TCHAR)` ?

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko: I'm not 100%, but I think that will work, although your buffer will sometimes be too large, because you are printing mostly ascii into the buffer in Unicode case.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use: [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) / swnprintf, it will return you number of chars/wchars needed.
2. here `char buff[size] = {0};` you are writing outside of the buffer. UPDATE: I'll take that back - it just a declaration with initialization if *size* is constant.
3. this `"%s (ID: %i)"` shall be changed to this: `"%s (ID: %d)"` if last parameter is `int`.

Comment: Ad. 2 (*here `char buff[size] = {0};` you are writing outside of the buffer.*) - how can I write outside of the buffer here, as I didn't defined its size yet - that's what I'm actually asking about.

Comment: Just be aware that only the MS version of snprintf has this behavior, generally snprintf returns number of characters written. http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf